# Reputation in side-bar not matching profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, ios-app

I've noticed a delay in the reputation score updating in the sidebar of the iOS app, but viewing my profile through the app shows the correct reputation.

Below is the sidebar, note the score for StackOverflow:
[image: sidebar]

And below is the profile for SO in the app, again note the score:
[image: profile]

I had some upvotes and an answer a few mins before this, so seems to be some sort of delay in the process that updates the sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The reputation shown in the menu is part of the network user cache used throughout the app (mainly as a quick way of checking for site membership or checking if you own a post).

Other than reputation, we don't expect this to change very often without direct interaction on mobile.  Specifically, we only check for changes every 10 minutes and then we don't normally block on the update, instead showing the old values at that moment.

That said, opening the menu is (in your case) an explicit request to show reputation so it's a good time to reload that cache.  Now we will:

1. Continue opening the menu in a non-blocking way displaying old values so it opens instantly.
2. When opening, also reload the network users.  When they come in, update the reputation numbers.

This way things stay responsive and your rep stays up-to-date.

Comment: Excellent - and thanks for the explanation, makes sense and good to know :-)